# Declared a const outside a react component to use it in different places

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to use ABC in different places, I use to have the same definition in this two places but the I extract it outside the component.

Is this a react way to do this or are there better ways?

```
 const ABC = {
    jane: 0,
    john: 1
  };

 class ProjectPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      resetIdCounter();
    }

   static async getInitialProps({ query }) {
      return { query, variable:ABC[query.name] };
   }

  render() {
    //code that use ABC
  }
}
```

Comment: This is fine. You can put it in a separate file and import it into each component you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a parallel file in you project, ex `myConfig.js`. Inside this file, export this const like

```
export const ABC = {
    jane: 0,
    john: 1,
 };
```

Then import this newly created `myConfig.js` in your above said react file (`ProjectPage`) like:

```
import * as myConfig from './myConfig';
// or import only what you need directly
import { ABC } from './myConfig';
```

Now, just use wherever you want in this file like `myConfig.ABC`;